# Can I change a value from within a Constraint or ConstraintValidator?

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony, silex

I'm using the Form component in my own stack, and I need to create a constraint/validator pair.

The problem is that I need to modify the value inside the constraint. Eg: if the value is 123, change it to 456.

How can I do this? I need it to be handled by the constraint or validator, as I don't want to repeat that logic all over the place.

Comment: You really don't want validators to change your data.  Have you looked at DataTransformers? http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html?  If those don't work for you then perhaps you can provide a bit more detail on why you need to change the value.

Answer (score 2):

In your custom constraint,  you can access to the variable `$object` if it's a form class constraint. 
You should be able to call set methods during your validation.

So, in your custom Constraint class:

```
public function getTargets()
    {
      return self::CLASS_CONSTRAINT;
    }
```

In your custom ConstraintValidator

```
 public function validate($object, Constraint $constraint)
    {
    /*
    *  thensomewhere in  the code 
    */
    if($object->getNumber() == 123){
       $object->setNumber(456);
    }
```

some helping sources:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html